# Issue with VS Code and python preview extension

Tags: python, visual-studio

im new using VS Code, and im not able to get to work a plugin called "Python preview"

Im using Ubuntu 20.04 and VS code 1.46.1.
When i try to "open preview on the side" of any .py file, its tries to open but close suddenly raising always this issue:
"Failed to launch the Python Process, please validate the path 'python'"

I suspect that this might happen with other extensions.
Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Follow these steps and it will be OK:

1. [How To Install Anaconda on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart)
2. reload the vs code
3. try python preview in vs code